# SQL Server - Update column from data in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
SetId      ID       Premium
2012        5          Y
2012        6          Y
2013        5          N
2013        6          N
```

I want to update the 2013 records with the premium values where the setid equals 2012.

So after the query it would look like this:

```
SetId      ID       Premium
2012        5          Y
2012        6          Y
2013        5          Y
2013        6          Y
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: `the 2013 records` - please clarify this part. Is this stored somewhere in your DB? or it is just another explanation of `SetId` column?

Comment: @dawsonz: What is your expected output, if "first record of 2012 premium is 'N'"?

Comment: I want to copy the Premium column where the ID is the same from those records with 2012 to those records with 2013.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's not clear which 2012 value you want to use to update which 2013 value, i've assumed that the `ID` should be the same.

Full example using table variables that you can test yourself in management studio.

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (
    SetId INT,
    Id INT, 
    Premium VARCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES (2012, 5, 'Y')
INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES (2012, 6, 'Y')
INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES (2013, 5, 'N')
INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES (2013, 6, 'N')

--Before Update
SELECT * FROM @Tbl 

--Something like this is what you need
UPDATE t 
SET t.Premium = t2.Premium 
FROM @Tbl t 
INNER JOIN @Tbl t2 ON t.Id = t2.Id 
WHERE t2.SetId = 2012 AND t.SetId = 2013

--After Update    
SELECT * FROM @Tbl
```

Comment: thank's chris the example was very helpful to play around.

Comment: We used this solution.  However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094023/sql-server-update-column-from-data-in-the-same-table) question may be relevant.

Comment: May I know why *this* is used to redirect to the same page.?

Answer (score 17):

```
UPDATE t 
SET t.Premium = (SELECT TOP 1 t2.Premium
                 FROM dbo.TableName t2
                 WHERE t2.SetId = 2012)
FROM dbo.TableName t
WHERE t.SetId = 2013
```

<kbd>[**Demonstration**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8405f/3/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 10):

I think this is correct solution:

```
UPDATE t 
SET t.Premium = (SELECT TOP 1 t2.Premium
                 FROM dbo.TableName t2
                 WHERE t2.SetId = 2012 AND t2.Id = t.ID)
FROM dbo.TableName t
WHERE t.SetId = 2013
```

Comment: Very good point Chris I've just tested and realised this, thank you.

Comment: Oops, deleted the comment. It was that you should note the subtle difference between this answer and my own in that, if there is not matching entry with `SetId = 2012` and the same `ID` then it will try to update the `t.Premium` to `NULL`, which may fail depending on the table schema and whether the column allows null values.

Answer (score 6):

We can  update table from self table, like this:

```
update TABLE_A 
   set TABLE_A.Col1=B.Col2
  from TABLE_A B
```

Answer (score 5):

There is **ABSOLUTELY** no need to go to all those fancy lengths suggested by the accpeted answer using `INNER JOIN`s **or** `FROM`s **or** `aliases` when updating from the same table - see the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=4aaee9d78570c6a08767bc090478ae8b)!

```
CREATE TABLE b (x INT, y INT);
```

Populate:

```
INSERT INTO b (x) VALUES (2), (3), (4);
```

Check:

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

Result:

```
x   y
2   null
3   null
4   null
```

Now - just simply:

```
UPDATE b SET y = x
WHERE x <= 3;
```

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM b;
```

Result:

```
x   y
2   2
3   3
4   null
```

Et voilà - perfectly simple! Antoine de Saint-Exupéry was [right](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/72083-la-perfection-est-atteinte-non-pas-lorsqu-il-n-y-a-plus):

> “La perfection est atteinte, non pas lorsqu'il n'y a plus rien à
>   ajouter, mais lorsqu'il n'y a plus rien à retirer.”

> Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but
>   when there is nothing left to take away.

Answer (score 0):

If you also need to directly copy a value from one specific record to another specific record in the same table do something like this:

```
update DEST
set DEST.field1 = SRC.field1,
from TableName DEST
INNER JOIN TableName SRC
on DEST.ID = @DestId and SRC.ID = @SourceID
```