# sorting data and move to new columns in sql

Tags: sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK91S.jpg)I have  three columns in sql. First column include variable name and second column include variable value. I want to sort variable name based on its values and put sorting result in third column. For doing this, I used following query.

```
select variablename
from table1
order by variablevalue Asc
```

I  see sorting result in Result part when i execute my query but i can not move to third column.

Comment: can you share your query or expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by putting the sorting result in the third column? What exactly is supposed to go in that column?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: What is your RDMS?

Comment: This similar question might be [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094023/sql-server-update-column-from-data-in-the-same-table)

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the below solution:

```
Create table #Students(Roll integer,Name varchar(255));

Insert into #Students values(11,'Shubh');
Insert into #Students values(2,'Ankit');
Insert into #Students values(3,'Ankit');
Insert into #Students values(14,'Ankit');

select a.roll, a.name, b.roll, b.name from 
((select roll, name,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (select null))col  from #Students) a 
join
(select roll,name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY roll asc)col1  from #Students) b on 
a.col = b.col1)
```

Result:

```
roll    name    roll    name
11      Shubh   2      Ankit
 2      Ankit   3      Ankit
 3      Ankit   11     Shubh
14      Ankit   14     Ankit
```

Comment: hi.thank you for  your replying.                                                                                                   select a.roll, a.name, b.roll, b.name from                                                                      what does it mean?

Comment: It means a.roll, a.name this is actual result and b.roll,b.name means your sorted result. you see the output result.

Comment: When i execute your query,four columns are created as result that  they have not shown sorted variable name.four columns have shown same values

Comment: Please share your query with result and sample data

Comment: ((select FANVALUE, FANRESULT,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (select null))col  from MOVHOFA) a 
join
(select FANVALUE,FANRESULT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY FANVALUE asc)col1  from MOVHOFA) b on 
a.col = b.col1);

Comment: I do not know,how to send pic in here.do you have facebook account or gmail?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want a rank, then use `rank()`:

```
select variablename, variablevalue,
       rank() over (order by variablevalue) as ordering
from table1
order by variablevalue Asc;
```

Comment: i want to change sorting result in table.when i executed query,i have not seen results in table