# update join causes error: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to do an update as follows:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.PackageID = p.ID
FROM gym.Account a
JOIN Packages p
ON a.MembershipTypeID = p.MembershipTypeID
and a.SiteID = p.SiteID
and a.SiteID = 1
```

I get the error message

> Subquery returned more than 1 value

I don't see how this error message could be accurate because when I query:

```
select 
    ID, SiteID, PackageName, MembershipTypeID
from 
    Packages
where 
    siteid = 1
order by 
    MembershipTypeID, PackageName
```

...the `MembershipTypeID` values are all unique -- no duplicates!

So then I looked at the [Stack question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121161/sql-update-query-and-subquery-returned-more-than-one-value), and tried this:

```
UPDATE gym.Account  
SET PackageID = (SELECT top 1 ID
                 FROM Packages
                 WHERE gym.Account.MembershipTypeID = MembershipTypeID)
```

Yet I still get the same error message, even though I'm doing a TOP 1. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this statement generate only one row per MembershipTypeID combo?
select a.PackageID
, p.ID
FROM gym.Account a
JOIN Packages p
ON a.MembershipTypeID = p.MembershipTypeID
and a.SiteID = p.SiteID
and a.SiteID = 1

Comment: Is Gym.Account a table or a view?  Also, do you have any triggers on it?

Comment: Ahhhhhhh! There is a trigger on it! I had forgotten. I didn't connect that error message with the existence of a trigger. THANKS DeadZone! It works after disabling the trigger. Why don't you post your answer, so it can help others...

Comment: Answer posted.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check to see if there is a trigger on the table.  That could be the source of your error.

:)

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Needed to disable trigger first. Would be nice if MS added to the error message: "Hey dummy, you have a trigger on this table..."